# Getting "Object does not contain a definition for xxx" using LabelFor in a strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

Having an issue in my MVC3 Razor application (ASP.NET) when I try to access the view 
The Model looks like this (annotations removed)

```
namespace MvcTest.Models {
        public class ContactMeModel {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The View has something like this (partial, just putting the part that gives the error, doesn't get past that...

```
@model MvcTest.Models.ContactMeModel
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "test"
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.From)
    </div>
}
```

The namespaces are correct, but the intellisense shows red on the .From part of the markup as if it doesn't recognize the model but this happens with views that work too.

When I access the View I get the following error:

```
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'From' and no extension method 'From' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

That is strange because (a) The Mvc web project HAS a reference to the DLL that contains the models (b) The entire project has been cleaned and rebuilt (c) The model reference in the view has the correct fully qualified model name (d) the model class exists (e) there are no compilation errors except at run time on that view.

By the way, the error occurrs *anywhere* I have @Html.LabelFor, so for example the stock LogOn.cshtml has a line that produces the same error:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
```

And in the "intellisense" I see the "UserName" text underlined with a zig-zagged red line and the intellisense mentions the same error. But if on the same page I hover the @model line on the model name and do "Go to Definition" VS takes me to the definition. So, it knows what the model is but then not quite?! If the model namespace is incorrect I do get a "navigation" error when I select "Go to definition".

The controller action method  looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new Coralys.PanamaVibes.Mvc.Models.ContactMeModel());
    }
```

so yes, it returns the right model and not an anonymous type.

Comment: are you sure that you code builds successfully? build your code from the view that it's getting troubles

Comment: Have you tried setting VS to compile views? Instructions here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=698

Comment: @Jorge Yes it builds successfully, no errors only at runtime.

Comment: @hatchet thanks for the interesting lead. I just enabled it on Release. However, I get no view compilation errors but an error on web.config complaining that my system.web/authentication element is in error because it is a MachineToApplication section but it is actually my application's root web.config. So with that enabled I can't get further.

Comment: are you sure you return the right thing from your action method?(though that would not explain the intellisence issue)

Comment: Do you have the namespace MvcTest.Models listed in the Web.config in your views folder?

Comment: @LordofScripts -when you get a MachineToApplication web.config error in VS, it is often bogus. Very often you can solve it by deleting the bin AND obj folders and rebuilding. Clean is not enough.

Comment: @Bond just updated the question as you can see it returns the correct model.

Comment: @Carl yes, I have it in the <add namespace=""/> on the <system.web.webPages.razor><pages> section of the web.config in the Views folder.

Comment: @hatchet This MVC stuff seems flaky. My controllers/models/etc are in a separate assembly that is referenced and the namespaces are OK. I just tried moving those to the same project as the MVC application but the problem persists (BTW now I get the errors at compile using that Build Views hint. However, it can navigate to the model without problem.

Comment: @hatchet the MvcBuildView hint is also buggy. I created a barebones MailController that worked on another MVC and placed it on this solution. During build or even intellisense does not mark any error in that (Release build with Build Views enabled) and yet when executing it at runtime the error pops up like all the other forms. This is very puzzling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spent the whole day scouring the internet and researching. I compared my old solution and the new one and found the culprit.

As it turns out other than the difference in content and some other code behind, the main diference was that in the broken solution I had implemented a **custom webviewpage** ! This came to me in a moment of enlightment. So that brought me to the next question, Why does it break only strongly-typed views and yet it is able to navigate to the models?

The simple answer is, the custom webviewpage is made up of a regular version and a generic version. The generic version is used for strongly-typed views.

I examined the custom webviewpage which I had enhanced from a contribution by @haacked on his blog. One of the very last comments on that blog was of a person (Matthew) who had used it with strongly typed views and experienced the same problem. So, the solution was to modify the generic version of the custom webviewpage so that rather than inheriting from the custom non-generic version, it would inherit from WebViewPage instead. Then all strongly typed views worked again and the CS1061 error went away.

I also strongly recommend the tip by @hatchet, to enable the BuildViews in the Release version (not in Debug as it lengthens the rebuild phase).

The example of a Custom WebViewPage, though broken as posted is **highly** useful, now I am able to create my own helpers without overcrowding the Html and Url helpers. Strangely enough, when I looked for something like that his was the only real article that dealt with the issue of making your custom helpers in MVC3.

Comment: Nice hint for me. In short, I fix by declaring class like this `public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>`. Note the last `<TModel>` fix the error.